# How do I handle images in a Git repo?

Tags: git, github

I have inherited a medium sized iOS project - ~30,000 lines of code - that has an **insane** number of image assets. Of course we use Git/Github to scm. Currently the images are included in the directory tree and thus gets ingested into the repo, bloating the heck out of it and generally making development a big headache.

We have 4 devs on the project, some virtual. It occurs to me to move the images to Dropbox, refer to them from the iOS project and keep things ship shape.

Does anyone have a comment on this idea? What do you do do deal with image/video/audio files in a Git scm setup?

Comment: for example, some people prefer opening braces on new lines, some use lots of empty lines, some put their function names on the line after the return type, etc etc…

Comment: What do you mean by _images are included in the directory tree and thus gets ingested into the repo, bloating the heck out of it_? You either store assets in your server (and yes, they live **in your directory tree**), or you use some cdns. It's not clear why you complain. Looks like you imagine some other way to have and serve assets we don't know about. Could you please explain?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I'd be pretty nervous about that, actually; what if you want to update an image, then change your mind? Or what if you need to build a maintenance release with old images?

If this is really a problem -- and I've never seen this actually be a problem in practice, but I'll take your word for it -- why not just use one repo for the images, another for everything else? You can then just be lazy about syncing the image one.

Comment: This is how I deal with art assets in Mercurial.  It works quite well.

Comment: @Ernest, the problem comes during the maelstrom of activity that happens before app submission to the App Store. You end up with screenfuls of Git shite flying across the screen, most of which is harmless but hidden amongst the muck could be something important. Its the ceaseless clutter that I find annoying and confusing.

Comment: @Ernest, Is there a .gitignore or .gitattributes that can help filter the git diagnostic noise?

Comment: If you could be a bit more specific about what you mean by "screenfuls of Git shite" I imagine that someone could help you decode it...

Comment: @Ernest, On balance I have to agree with you that assets in a git repo fall into the "not a real problem" bucket. Yes, my repo bloats, but ultimately, that is the nature of the beast. Cheers.

Comment: It's a big problem when your repo size is 1.9GB/2GB of which 2/3 is images. Even splitting the images to a separate repository is only a temporary measure when you have a large number of assets... and doing so makes it a little more difficult to manage releases.

Answer (score 18):

It can be a bit of a pain to deal with, but what I've used in the past are [submodules](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule) for images and media. That way, you can pull down just your code without getting the images if you want to, but you can still keep your images and media in sync with your code. When the submodule history would get too big, we could just create a new repo without the history, and swap out the old submodule for the new one. That way, people could be in sync with the latest version of the media, without having to pull the full history.

We would frequently start out with green screens of our video in the submodule, so we could develop with the video before it was in its final form, but once it was composited, we would break the submodule history and push out a new submodule that had just the composited videos. That avoided having an entire extra copy of every video, while still allowing you (with a little manual work of swapping the submodules around) to get the old version out if you needed to.

Submodules will increase the amount of work that you will need to do. If you want to commit changes to your images, you need to change them in the submodule, commit that, push it, then go to the parent project, commit the change to the submodule, and push that. For simple cases you can write some scripts to make this a little easier, but in more complicated cases like merge conflicts it will be considerably more complicated than using a single project for everything.

Answer (score 15):

[`git-lfs`](https://git-lfs.github.com/) appears to be a good modern solution to this problem. It tracks files as local text pointers in your repo, while storing them on an external large file store. This is kind of like the subrepo solution, but without the need for as much manual intervention.

On the one hand, this makes you more dependent on having internet access--you probably won't be able to switch between branches as fully if you can't access the external file store. On the other hand, it means that you're not downloading the entire history of every binary file when you clone a repo.

It's supported by [GitHub](https://github.com/blog/1986-announcing-git-large-file-storage-lfs), [Visual Studio Online](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2015/10/01/announcing-git-lfs-on-all-vso-git-repos/), and [Bitbucket Server](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/git-large-file-storage-794364846.html).

Answer (score 10):

I haven't used it myself, but there is a project called [git media](https://github.com/alebedev/git-media) which is designed to make it easier to work with big binary files like images in git. It's from Scott Chacon who's kind of a big deal in the git world, so I imagine it probably works quite well.

Answer (score 3):

I find git to be the wrong tool for the job when it comes to dealing with binary source.

Finalized assets that your software requires inorder to be considered "complete" would be best kept committed in your repo but I would seek out an alternative solution for working with actual image source such as an ai file or psd.

Git offers little if any benefit for working with these files and as you stated, it bloats the repo which negatively effects areas where git offers actual benefit.

I myself have considered dropbox, but I feel the need for a more tailored solution. One that allows me to quickly sync across computers, automatically stores that last ten versions or so, allows me to preserve and name specific versions and supports locking of files (Read: avoid need to try and merge binary files.) This is a different tool for a different job/workflow. Sadly I know not of it's existence, but I would love to see it come to be.

Comment: Yeah, in that case I would just keep in in the repo or be sorry later :/. You can use a git submodule (http://bit.ly/aDvmTJ) to contain the madness if there really is a lot. Also, do an audit, what in there is actually being used or provides value. If it turns out to be a bunch of junk delete stuff.

Answer (score 1):

I have been interested in this issue. In my meanderings I came across git annex: http://git-annex.branchable.com Haven't used it because my server provider doesn't have it installed.

Answer (score -1):

You can store the image and binaries using Subversion system (SVN). The images and other binaries are not going to change very often, but still you can get notified when those files are changed or updated centrally.

Git is best for version-ing only source code and only include source codes in Github.

Subversion and Git both together can give you total versioning of all things.

Comment: I'd think that combining two types of source control would add a lot of complexity