# Is it ok to keep a (considerably small) number of images/binary data in a git repo?

Tags: git, github

Related: [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5756324/how-do-i-handle-images-in-a-git-repo).

In the above question the OP was asking about a project with a lot of binary data (i.e., images). I have a somewhat similar problem but of a smaller scale. I'm working on a project which is hosted on github. The project is an application with GUI, hence I have some images that will be used.

The amount of images is considerably small (probably not more than a hundred), and most of them are small PNGs. Since I work from different machines, it is important for me to be able to get a complete set of resources for building each time. Now I'm unsure what should I do with the images. This far, I can think of two options:

- Keep the images in the repo alongside with the code (they are unlikely to be changed, btw, but new ones might be added later)
- Keep the images elsewhere (e.g. on a cloud storage) and download them each time I need them.

I would be happy to go with the first one, thus my question is:

Will keeping binary data in the repo affect it in an unwanted manner (make it slower, or drastically increase it's size or anything else)? Or, considering the amount of data I have, I shouldn't worry about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We develop a moderately large web application and so we do have the usual images going around just as well. I have not seen any adverse effects whatsoever.

So, in my opinion, this is perfectly fine. I would much rather have everything I need for the build packed into one repo and versioned together.

Answer (score 1):

You can have binaries in git repos. It is not very efficient regarding change sets, but git can live with that.

Your images will probably not change a lot, so this is not a big problem.

I have git repos with Excel files etc. It works. I prefer to have the stuff in my repo, not somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say look again at the answer for the question you reference.  This just isn't really a problem (especially for you with a small amount of assets).

If you put your images in the cloud you won't have a traceable history. So no easy reverting to previous images, re-instating of deleted images, and all the other version control benefits.